# How can I automate making variables from an object global?

Tags: javascript, math, object, global

I want to make a function that automatically turns every "Math" function global

example:

```
floor = Math.floor
```

This allows me to do this:

```
alert(floor(2.5))
```

The example above works perfectly (it alerts "2"), but I can't seem to find a way to automate this process for every function in the "Math" object. I looked on the internet and I tried to make something myself but... nothing works.

answer:

```
(function(a,b){for(b in a=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math))this[a[b]]=Math[a[b]]})()
```

Comment: I don't think you can...

Comment: Why? What is the reason for doing this?

Comment: @epascarello I think that the Math object is a bad part of javascript, and I want to fix it. For my personal use.

Comment: So your ideal solution is to pollute the window scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you might think you could just loop over all the properties from the `Math` object and turn any function into a global one (by copying its reference):

```
for( var prop in Math ) {
    if( typeof Math[ prop ] === 'function' ) {
        window[ prop ] = Math[ prop ];
    }
}
```

This would work.. **if** the word *would* wouldn't be here :)

We can discover the problem with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`:

```
console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Math, 'floor') );
```

..and as we can see, all `methods` are set to `enmuerable` `false`.

---

*edit*

I actually forgot about `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. You indeed could get all property names with that method, like

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math).forEach(function(name) {
    if( typeof Math[name] === 'function' )
        window[name] = Math[name];
});
```

Comment: @RayToal: yes your answer totally made up my mind. Thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Thanks allot! It's what Ive been looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Like so

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math).forEach(function (p) {
    window[p] = Math[p];
});

alert(floor(4.5));
alert(sqrt(100));
```

​
`getOwnPropertyNames` gives all properties in the object, not just the enumerable ones.

This works in a browser, where the global object is called `window`.  For other JS environments you might need something different.

[A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yRDcR/)

Comment: Thanks allot! It's what Ive been looking for!